# MavenCli output to eclipse/maven console

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse

I have an elipse RCP application which uses Maven Surefire for special tests.
Maven is integrated via m2e into the application.

The user builds his project in my application and wants to test parts of his project.

Now it's possible to start the maven test command from within my code and it works perfectly but the logging output is not printed to my application's console but to my IDE's console.

```
public class MyAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {

private IFolder selectedFolder;
private IPath path;

@Override
public void run(IAction action) {
    String flagValue = foo();
    String projectLocation = bar();

    PrintStream out = System.out; // <- here

    MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
    cli.doMain(new String[] {"test", "-DmyFlag=" + flagValue}, 
            projectLocation, out, out);
}
```

How can I get the mavenCli to print to my application's console?

Comment: Why are you calling Maven command line instead of using usual unit/integration test setup related to surefire as you already mentioned ?

Comment: I want the user to be able to test the project he has created in my application. He specifies dependencies and properties in the pom file in his project and can run maven surefire tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a way to print to the application's console from MavenCLI. In the action that is triggered by the user I am starting a Job:

```
public class MyAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {

private IFolder selectedFolder;
private IPath path;

@Override
public void run(IAction action) {
    String flagValue = foo();
    String projectLocation = bar();

    MyJob runTestCaseJob = new MyJob(flagValue , projectLocation);
        runTestCaseJob.schedule();
}
```

And in the Job class I'm starting the MavenCLI:

```
public class MyJob extends Job {

private static final String TASK_NAME = "Starting the Maven Command";

private String myFlag;
private String projectLocation;

private final PrintStream out = getConsole();
private final MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();

public MyJob(String myFlag, String projectLocation) {
    super(TASK_NAME);
    this.myFlag = myFlag;
    this.projectLocation = projectLocation;
}

@Override
protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    cli.doMain(new String[] {"test", "-DmyFlag=" + myFlag}, 
            projectLocation, out, out);
    return Status.OK_STATUS;
}

private PrintStream getConsole() {
    MessageConsole console = findMessageConsole("Console");
    console.activate();
    return new PrintStream(console.newOutputStream());
}

private MessageConsole findMessageConsole(String title) {
    IConsole[] existingConsoles = ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().getConsoles();
    for (IConsole existingConsole : existingConsoles) {
        if (existingConsole.getName().equals(title)) {
            return (MessageConsole) existingConsole;
        }
    }
    MessageConsole console = new MessageConsole(title, null);
    ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(new IConsole[] {console});
    return console;
}
```